# How to capture CTRL key PRESSED and RELEASED in my Windows application?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I would like to capture **CTRL** press in my Windows application. I am not interested in any "CTRL +" combination. I just want to know when **CTRL** key is **PRESSED** and **RELEASED**. It is needed in order to light up some toggle when Ctrl key is pressed.

Is there a way to get notification of that from Windows API?

Comment: Handle `WM_KEYDOWN` / `WM_KEYUP`?

Comment: CTRL activates WM_KEYDOWN for some reason sends wrong VK code. ALT does not activates WM_KEYDOWN at all.

Comment: I believe ALT sends WM_SYSKEYDOWN.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is probably to set up a timer and in the WM_TIMER handler to poll the state of the keys you care about via [GetAsyncKeyState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx)